# Are there IDEs that can detect stack depth failure?

Tags: contract-debugging, ide

for example, can browser-solidity, Mix or live.ether.camp debug stack depth failures?

Comment: how would 'debugging stack depth f' look like? You mean static analysis? Because BS certainly throws if the limit is reached